# Not Able to Create user using FirebasExceptin -->cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I am trying to create user but this exception is generated

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException**
Showing Toast Message Registration Unsuccessful!

**Trying from 2Days**

This is my Activity

```
package com.example.expensemanager;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText regEmail;
    private EditText regPassword;
    private Button btnReg;
    private TextView singin_here;

    private ProgressDialog mDialog;
    //Firebase
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);

        registration();
    }   // oncreate() Ends
    private void registration()
    {   regEmail=findViewById(R.id.email_reg);
        regPassword=findViewById(R.id.password_reg);
        btnReg=findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);
        singin_here=findViewById(R.id.signin_here);

        btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email=regEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password=regPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
                {
                    regEmail.setError("Email required!");
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
                {
                    regPassword.setError("Password Required!");
                    return;
                }
                //before will show progress Dialog
                mDialog.setMessage("Processing");
                mDialog.show();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {   mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registation Complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            try {
                                FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException) task.getException();
                                Log.e("RegistrationActivity", "Failed Registration", e);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Log.i("RegistrationActivity","someting");
                                System.out.println("this"+e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        singin_here.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**And This is build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.expensemanager"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true;
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'


}
```

**FireBase singin Enabled**

[image]

**Logcat**
[image]

Comment: You should log `task.getException()` to see what it actually returns before blindly assuming its type.

Comment: @DougStevenson i have Already log task.getException() please see in Activity Code

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you should not post images of text.  Copy the text into the question itself so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson can you please help me solving you can see Code above it will be really helpfull

Comment: Why not simply add, what Doug Stevenson asked for?

Comment: @AlexMamo please check above i have already used

FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException) task.getException();

read above code